# why undefined in the function of addEventListener?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I'm trying to add a `mouseenter` event listener to elements to change their childnodes' opacity. I use `for` to add the listener, and can output the childnodes properly, but in the function it's "undefined". I have no idea why.

HTML:

```
<article class="index-image-article rel">
    <section class="index-image-info">
        // some elements
     </section>
     <div class="index-image-excerpt mask table">
         // some elements
     </div>
</article>
```

Javascript:

```
var indexImageArticle = document.querySelectorAll(".index-image-article");
var indexImageInfo = document.querySelectorAll(".index-image-info");
var indexImageExcerpt = document.querySelectorAll(".index-image-excerpt");

for(var i = 0; i < indexImageArticle.length; i++) {
    console.log(indexImageInfo[i]); // output properly
    indexImageArticle[i].addEventListener("mouseenter", function() {
        indexImageInfo[i].style.opacity = 1;
        indexImageExcerpt[i].style.opacity = 0;
    });
}
```

the output of `console.log` is:

```
<section class=​"index-image-info">​…​</section>​
<section class=​"index-image-info">​…​</section>​
<section class=​"index-image-info">​…​</section>​
<section class=​"index-image-info">​…​</section>
```

and the error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined(anonymous function)`

​the `undefined` point to the `indexImageInfo[i]`

Comment: Try to imagine, what value `i` has at the moment, when the the event handler function is called.

Comment: As a follow up to @ctwheels comment, do you have any "index-image-article" elements that do not contain an "index-image-info" element?

Comment: This is the most infamous `closure inside loop` problem. At the time of execution(!) the loop variable `i` has reached its final state which is one higher than the highest loop value (in your case it's `indexImageArticle.length`). Somehow you'll have to generate a separate scope for a local copy of `i` in each loop. There are several ways to do this (e.g. function factory or IIFE)

Comment: @Jonathan I got "5  5  5"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is one of those strange nuances of variable scoping rules in javascript.

Really this boils down to one thing, at the point of adding the event handler, `i` has the right value. At the point of *executing* the event handler `i` has been incremented up to `indexImageArticle.length`, and is therefore outside of the bounds of the array.

It can be fixed by using a block which maintains the scope of the variable, a [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) is one way:

```
for(var i = 0; i < indexImageArticle.length; i++) {
    console.log(indexImageInfo[i]); // output properly
    (function(x){
        indexImageArticle[x].addEventListener("mouseenter", function() {
            indexImageInfo[x].style.opacity = 1;
            indexImageExcerpt[x].style.opacity = 0;
        });
    })(i)
}
```